# Read .csv file from dropbox and plot it on leaflet map in shiny app

Tags: r, csv, shiny, leaflet, dropbox

I have 4 stations that I want to plot on map. You can download [**the data from here.**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i9pw95ltjown2uc/stations.csv?dl=0)

Using the code below, I managed to plot them

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
stations <- read.csv("~path/stations.csv")
ui <- bootstrapPage(
tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "100%")) 
server <- function(input, output) {
output$map <- renderLeaflet({
leaflet(stations) %>%
  addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldTopoMap") %>%
  addCircleMarkers(~x,~y)
})
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

and here is the result

[image]

Now, in the final `shiny` app, I want to read the `.csv` file from dropbox.

Following the [method described in this link](https://exploredata.wordpress.com/2014/11/28/importing-data-from-dropbox-into-r/), I tried the following

```
library(repmis)
myfilename <- "stations.csv"
mykey <- "i9pw95ltjown2uc"
stations <- source_DropboxData(myfilename, key=mykey, sep=",", header=TRUE)
```

I got this error

> Error in source_DropboxData(myfilename, key = mykey, sep = ",", header = TRUE) : 
>     unused arguments (myfilename, key = mykey, sep = ",", header = TRUE)

Using [the answer in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299220/access-a-url-and-read-data-with-r), I tried

```
stations <- read.csv(url("https://www.dropbox.com/s/i9pw95ltjown2uc/stations.csv?dl=0"))
```

I got this error

> Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed

I tried the [answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854046/duplicate-row-names-are-not-allowed-error-in-r-programming)

```
stations <- read.csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/i9pw95ltjown2uc/stations.csv?dl=0",
 row.names=NULL)
```

but `str(stations)` showed it has 1465 observation.

```
#'data.frame':  1465 obs. of  2 variables:
```

Any suggestions how to read `.csv` from dropbox to be able to plot it on leaflet map would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `?raw=1` rather than `?dl`

```
stations <- read.csv(url("https://www.dropbox.com/s/i9pw95ltjown2uc/stations.csv?raw=1"))

> head(stations)
  stations         x       y
1 station1  -77.2803 35.8827
2 station2  -79.1243 42.4356
3 station3  -93.4991 30.0865
4 station4 -117.6321 34.0905
```

Reference [from dropbox website](https://www.dropbox.com/help/201)

Comment: Excellent answer! Thank you.