# How to read a CSV file with row.names = 1?

Tags: r, heatmap

I want to read a .csv file in R, in order to draw a heat map.
My .csv data looks like:

```
Label|AA|BB|CC|DD
YE1  |0.1|0.9|0.3|0.7|
YE2  |0.3|0.5|0.2|0.3|
NE1  |0.9|0.6|0.1|0.4|
NE2  |0.8|0.7|0.1|0.5|
```

AA to DD are features and Label represent the row names. I want to plot heat map of features vs Labels

In order to read a .csv file, I wrote the following:

```
data <- read.csv("C:/example.csv", row.names= 1)
```

But, this gives me an error.

> Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
>    duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed

I came across [reading a csv file with repeated row names in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066607/reading-a-csv-file-with-repeated-row-names-in-r) where the answer says set `row.names = NULL`. But I don't want to set `row.names = NULL`. I want to read the row names in the data frame. How to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Your file doesn’t *have* row names. It has five named columns. Incidentally, there’s a broad trend in R to consider row names as bad, and not to use them (because they’re proper part of a table, and should be treated as such!). I recommend doing the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way that I've found to do this is:

```
data <- read.csv("C:/example.csv")
rownames(data)=data[,1]
data=data[,-1]
```

Comment: Don’t mix `<-` and `=`. Choose one style and use it consistently.

Comment: and thanks @Konrad Rudolph for editing the question.

Comment: You can also use `tibble::column_to_rownames`